# what did not insert db by spring data jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```java
@Entity
public class Posts {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class PostsDetail {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @MapsId
  private Posts posts;

}
```

it is very simple shared key JPA code.

```java
  @Test
  void t1() {
    Posts posts = new Posts();
    Posts save = postsRepository.save(posts);

    PostsDetail postsDetail = new PostsDetail();
    postsDetail.setPosts(save);
    postsDetailRepository.save(postsDetail);
  }
```

it has error

error msg= detached entity passed to persist nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist

Comment: You shouldn't save Posts and PostsDetail separately. You can create proper object PostsDetail, fill it with Posts and save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your case resembles what has been described [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). Note that if the parent *entity* is not already saved, you have to save it from the dependent `PostsDetail`. So, it should be okay if you do the following:

```
Posts posts = new Posts(); 
//Posts savedPost = postsRepository.save(posts); // <-- here
PostsDetail postsDetail = new PostsDetail();
postsDetail.setPosts(posts); // <-- here
postsDetailRepository.save(postsDetail);
```

Since `save()` does not flush your data immediately, `savedPost` will remain not persisted when you do `postsDetailRepository.save(postsDetail);`